# Default copy constructor in cpp shallow or deep copy?

Tags: c++, deep-copy, shallow-copy

Does the default copy-constructor do a shallow or a deep copy in C++?

I am really confused with default copy constructor in cpp, as it does shallow copy or deep copy,  as when I did `v2=v1;` suppose `v1={1,2,3}`, now if I have done `v2[0]=1;` It does not get reflected but I heard it does shallow copy, can anybody please explain?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], we have no idea how your class looks like

Comment: C++ really doesn't have the concept of deep or shallow copies, just the concept of semantically correct copies for a particular class.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Unless academia steps in. Then all bets are off.

Comment: The default copy constructor copies the contents of variables, nothing more, nothing less.  If you have a copy constructor, then the code in the copy constructor is executed.

Comment: Tightly related: [What is the Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: More details on how `{1,2,3}` is being stored in `v1` is required to provide a complete answer.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't do either. It does a *memberwise* copy. I.e. it copies all the members of the class using their copy constructors. If those members have copy constructors that do a deep copy then you'll get a deep copy, if they do a shallow copy then you'll get a shallow copy, or they could do something else entirely.

Deep copy and shallow copy are not C++ concepts, instead C++ lets you do a deep or shallow copy as you prefer.

Comment: Note that this means if your class contains a pointer, the pointer and only the pointer is copied. You now have two objects pointing to the same thing. Depending on the ownership of this pointed-at thing, this may be bad.

Comment: A _memberwise_ copy **is** a shallow copy. A “deep” copy is one where the container object knows stuff about how to properly duplicate its referenced field objects.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is the wrong question.

First, C++ default copy/assign is memberwise; it recursively copies/assigns based on what the members do.

Well designed C++ types follow a few patterns in what they do when copied/assigned that lines up with 3 different kinds of primitive types; value, reference amd pointer semantics.

A value semantics type behaves like a value.  This corresponds to your "deep copy" roughly.  Modifying one variable that follows value semantics never changes another.  `std::vector` is a value semantics type, as is `int`, `double`, `std::string` and other `std` container types.  Value semantics are a strong pattern, and make reasoning about program behaviour easy.  Note that value semantics need not be implemented as values; vector is typically implemented as a triple of pointers, with construction/copying/etc overloaded.

A reference semantics type behaves like a C++ reference type -- `int&`.  This is not the same as a Java/C# reference.  C++ references are aliases;  `int& a=b;` means `a` is another name for `b`.  Then `a=7` makes both `a` and `b` equal `7`.  If you had another reference `c`, `a=c` would *not* rebind `a` to refer to `c`; it would change what `a` referred to to have the same value as what `c` referred to.

Complex objects with reference semantics are rare.

A pointer semantics is like reference semantics, but assignment rebinds who it points to.  Sometimes an additional operation, like `&`, is needed to create a new pointer.  A type with pointer semantics includes `std::reference_wrapper`, `std::string_view`, `std::shared_ptr<double>`, `gsl::span<char>` and `int*`.

Typically it is a bad idea to mix members with different semantics in the same type; the rule of 0/3/5 states that the best move/copy/assogn/ctor/dtor is the empty one.  Your resource management types use RAII and write those special members, the other types aggregate them.  Value semantics types are not used mixed with reference/pointer in order for the composite class to get coherant semantics.

TL;DR: it depends.  Read the documentation on your members.  Document what semantics your types have so users know what to expect.

Note, however, that reference semantics is incompatible with being stored in a std container.

Answer (score 0):

The implicitly generated copy constructor (and assignment operator) performs a shallow copy.

There is no difference between a shallow copy, and deep copy of a value type.

> now if I have done v2[0]=1; It does not get reflected

There is no reason to expect such operation to *get reflected* unless the type of `v2` is a referential type.

Comment: This was probably downvoted because it is unclear to someone unused to C++'s ability to have complex objects with value semantics.  To improve I'd advise elaborating about value/reference (and pointer) semantics, how member semantics impacts default semantics of a type, and how that flows back into deep/shallow conxept.  Because everything you said is true, but I suspect not useful to the OP as written.  Meh, maybe I'll just answer.

Comment: You said "There is no difference between a shallow copy, and deep copy of a value type", what does it mean? as they share the same memory (shallow copy) as this is the assignment operator.

Comment: @RobinKhurana It means that there is only one kind of copying of value types - there is no distinction between shallow and deep copy for them. `as they share the same memory` What share the same memory?