# Default member variables in defaulted copy/move constructors

Tags: c++

What exactly occurs to a member variable with a default value, during a defaulted copy/move construction? As so:

```cpp
struct A {bool a = true;};

A x;
x.a = false;
A y = x;
```

I can imagine a few different ways this works, equivalently written as

```cpp
struct A {bool a;}; //no default

//option 1
A::A(const A& other) noexcept : a(other.a) {}

//option 2
A::A(const A& other) noexcept : a(true) {a = other.a;}

//option 3
A::A(const A& other) noexcept {a = other.a;}

//option 4 (hopefully not)
A::A(const A& other) noexcept : a(true) {}
```

With the obvious exception that using these would make A not `TriviallyCopyable`

Comment: [Dupe1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71491967/default-copy-move-constructor-efficiency-different), [Dupe2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51406033/default-constructor-in-cpp-shallow-or-deep-copy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constructor must and will always initialize all the class data members.

Default initializers will be used in constructors where that data member isn't explicitly initialized. The default copy constructors will initialize each data member with a copy of the corresponding data member from the copied object, so default initializers won't be used.

This leads to a case where default initializers will be used in a copy constructor if it's user provided and it lacks that member initializer (thanks to NathanOliver for pointing this out).

E.g.:

```
A(whatever param) {}            // default initializer used
A(whatever param) : a{true} {}  // default initializer NOT used
A(const A&) = default;          // default initializer NOT used
A(const A&) : a{other.a} {}     // default initializer NOT used
A(const A&) {}                  // default initializer used
```

Comment: technically it does for constructors if you provide your own and forget to initialize the member: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19983168b3aaede4

Comment: @NathanOliver wow, I haven't thought of this case. Interesting. Thinking how to edit the a